# PLUpload works different on server than in development

Tags: asp.net, html, post, get, plupload

I am using PLUpload just fine on my development machine.
But when I move it to my ASP server, it stops working.

I have tracked the problem down to a difference in the headers that are sent but have yet to find a cause for the difference.

--------------- Development WORKS -------------------

```
POST /Syquest/Scripts/Upload.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7185
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------22876316948407
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=uj02euez2viug5hwxqxprqd3
Host: localhost:51566
Referer: http://localhost:51566
```

--------------- Server FAILS -------------------

```
GET /syquest/scripts/upload.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0yuvoy1jh2oyu4aocq5eojmw
Host: mywebsite.com
Referer: https://mywebsite.com/
```

What I find VERY strange is that the server says PLUPLOAD is trying to 'GET' instead of 'PUT' so ... I restricted the runtime to just the HTML5 but it does the same thing.
Any clue as to what might be causing this difference?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a url rewrite.
In this website, I rewrite the URL to lower case for SEO purposes.
That was causing a 301 rewrite to occur.
A 301 rewrite does NOT repost with the data, thus the request came in with nothing.
The fix (in this case) was to send the initial request in lower case.
This resulted in no 301 rewrite.